# How to fix CSRF issue in node-linkedin?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, npm, linkedin-api, csrf

I am using [node-linkedin](https://github.com/ArkeologeN/node-linkedin) for linkedin access from my web application.

#### Problem

```
Error { [CSRF Alert: Possible CSRF attack, state parameters do not match.] name: 'CSRF Alert' }
```

### Code

```
 var Linkedin = require('node-linkedin')('apikey', 'secret', 'callback');

 Linkedin.auth.getAccessToken(res, req.query.code, req.query.state, function (err, results) {

   if(err){
     return console.error("Error", err);
   }

    return res.redirect('/index');
 });
```

Any suggestion to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Found out issue with library.

When I scale my nodejs application to use more than 2 instances it gives error,

```
Error { [CSRF Alert: Possible CSRF attack, state parameters do not match.] name: 'CSRF Alert' }
```

As the "states" parameter in auth.js is using memory store it will create problem to scale application.

Scenario is

'/oauth/linkedin' goes to **App-0** (creates state parameter "xxxx" + store in memory)
'/oauth/linkedin/callback' goes to **App-1** (here it will check if received state is "xxxx" + check if in memory)

Logged issue [here](https://github.com/ArkeologeN/node-linkedin/issues/56)

**Used sticky session in nginx to resolve this for now.**